# Can't create user on AD via keycloak API

Tags: active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to create user on AD via keycloak api.

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/admin/realms/Internal/users

[pic from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FO90.png)
but got the response back as follows:

```
"errorMessage": "Could not create user"
```

I set User Federation > Sync Registrations = ON

I looked at the log on server keycloak.

> 2022-07-21 16:55:20,526 WARN
> [org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource]
> (executor-thread-441) Could not create user:
> org.keycloak.models.ModelException: RDN Attribute [CN] is not filled.
> Filled attributes: {whenChanged=[], whenCreated=[], mail=[],
> sAMAccountName=[strange4], givenName=[ ], sn=[ ]}
> at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPUtils.computeAndSetDn(LDAPUtils.java:111)
> at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPUtils.addUserToLDAP(LDAPUtils.java:80)
> at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.addUser(LDAPStorageProvider.java:289)
> at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$addUser$9(UserStorageManager.java:244)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
> at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.addUser(UserStorageManager.java:246)
> at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.addUser(UserCacheSession.java:781)
> at org.keycloak.userprofile.AbstractUserProfileProvider$1.apply(AbstractUserProfileProvider.java:259)
> at org.keycloak.userprofile.AbstractUserProfileProvider$1.apply(AbstractUserProfileProvider.java:246)
> at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultUserProfile.create(DefaultUserProfile.java:87)
> at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.createUser(UsersResource.java:157)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor770.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:67)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:55)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:380)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:358)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
> at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$1(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:71)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
> at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
> at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You forgot to post the code you're using to submit the request to the API :)

Comment: I attached additional image files from postman.

Comment: The error says the "CN" field is not filled. Doesn't it ring a bell for you? Have you missed any mapping/configurations?